# How can I migrate from In-App Billing Plugin 4.0.2 to 6.7.0? I get some errors when I try to use 6.7.0

Tags: c#, xamarin

https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/InAppBillingPlugin

I'm trying to migrate from In-App Billing Plugin 4.0.2 to 6.7.0 but I get the following errors in my Verify.cs:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Plugin.InAppBilling;
using AndroidProject;
using SharedCode;
  
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(Verify))]
namespace AndroidProject
{
    public class Verify : IInAppBillingVerifyPurchase
    {
        const string key1 = @"...";
        const string key2 = @"...";
        const string key3 = @"...";

        public string SignedDataverify = "Test", Signatureverify = "Test";
        public Task<bool> VerifyPurchase(string signedData, string signature, string productId = null, string transactionId = null)
        {
            var key1Transform = InAppBillingImplementation.InAppBillingSecurity.TransformString(key1, 1);
            var key2Transform = InAppBillingImplementation.InAppBillingSecurity.TransformString(key2, 2);
            var key3Transform = InAppBillingImplementation.InAppBillingSecurity.TransformString(key3, 3);
            SignedDataverify = signedData;
            Signatureverify = signature;
            return Task.FromResult(InAppBillingImplementation
                .InAppBillingSecurity.VerifyPurchase(key1Transform + key2Transform + key3Transform, signedData, signature));
        }
    }
}
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSC9L.png)

I use now Microsoft.Maui.Essentials instead of Xamarin.Essentials. I have removed the NuGet packages Xamarin.Essentials and Xamarin.Forms from my Android/iOS projects. But now I get this error:

> Error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Forms' does not exist in the namespace 'Xamarin' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

And the following error:

> InAppBillingImplementation does not contain a definition for InAppBillingSecurity.

Is it still necessary to use the Xamarin.Forms NuGet package in my iOS and Android projects if I want to use In-App Billing Plugin 6.7.0 or can I use In-App Billing Plugin 6.7.0 with Microsoft.Maui.Essentials?
What is the problem with InAppBillingSecurity? Is it no more possible to use this code from version 4.0.2 to secure the purchases? Can I remove Verify.cs from my projects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it still necessary to use the Xamarin.Forms NuGet package in my iOS and Android projects if I want to use In-App Billing Plugin 6.7.0 or can I use In-App Billing Plugin 6.7.0 with Microsoft.Maui.Essentials?

You used `Dependency` attribute. It belongs to Xamarin.Forms namespace. So it is necessary to use the Xamarin.Forms NuGet package. For more information, you can refer to [Dependency Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction) by official. By the way, is your project Xamarin.Forms or MAUI?

> What is the problem with InAppBillingSecurity? Is it no more possible to use this code from version 4.0.2 to secure the purchases? Can I remove Verify.cs from my projects?

I tested the code you provided, and also encountered this error: `InAppBillingImplementation does not contain a definition for InAppBillingSecurity.` But back to 4.0.2, it works well. You can refer to ['InAppBillingImplementation' does not contain a definition for 'HandleActivityResult'](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/InAppBillingPlugin/issues/308). Author gave
advice. I think you can continue to use 4.0.2. I also see your issue [(I get some errors after migrating from 4.0.2 to 6.7.0)](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/InAppBillingPlugin/issues/515) on GitHub, and you can follow up it to wait author's reply. In addition, you can check the [README.md](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/InAppBillingPlugin/blob/master/docs/README.md) by author.

Comment: I found out that I don't need Verify.cs from the old 4.0.2 in 6.7.0. I will try to use 6.7.0 in my project.